# Calculate a t-test returning the test value an p-value

Tags: python

Working on a class assignment, given the instructions, can you help me understand what is wrong with my code?

I need to calculate a t-test returning the test value and the p-value for two sets of variables. As in the previous challenge, you’ll use a preloaded DataFrame that contains information about medical costs in different regions of the country and across other demographics, including age, sex, BMI (body mass index), number of children, and smoker vs. non-smoker.

For this challenge, you’ll focus on evaluating the sets sex and charges, and sex and bmi.

You’ll also start with preloaded code that creates two separate DataFrames, each containing all the columns and rows for sex equal to male or female, and the resulting DataFrames are named df_male and df_female, respectively. Your solution will use these new DataFrames. Also, you’ll be assigning values to two variables at once, as you did in the previous challenge.

For the t-test between sex and charges, assign the test value to the variable tc and the p-value to pc. Print out both results.
For the t-test between sex and bmi, assign the test value to the variable tb and the p-value to pb. Print out both results.
You’ll notice that only one of them has a significant p-value (less than 0.05), and your solution should confirm that it is the test that evaluates charges, not bmi.

CODE

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

df = pd.read_csv

# Create two separate DataFrames for sex
df_male = df.loc[df[‘sex’] == ‘male’]
df_female = df.loc[df[‘sex’] == ‘female’]

# Run a t-test comparing the charges column between males and females and print the results
tc, pc = stats.ttest(df_male, df_female)
print(tc)
print (pc)

# Run a t-test comparing the bmi column between males and females and print the results
tb, pb = stats.ttest(df_male, df_female)
print(tb)
print (pb)
```

Comment: Besides the `df =  pd.read_csv` line, which is missing the actual function call (it should be something like `df = pd.read_csv("name_of_the_file")` there is nothing wrong with the code. What is the error you are getting? Why do you say it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think we are in the same program lol I have been stuck on this questions for days but I finally solved it

```
# Run a t-test comparing the charges column between males and females and print the results
tc, pc = stats.ttest_ind(df_male.charges, df_female.charges)
print(tc, pc)

# Run a t-test comparing the bmi column between males and females and print the results
tb, pb = stats.ttest_ind(df_male.bmi, df_female.bmi)
print(tb, pb)
```